# Search duplicates and fill list with them

Tags: c#, list, linq, duplicates

I made some code in Linqpad to find duplicates and it works fine, but i've got a single list of duplicates List. Now, i'd like to get an IEnumerable> with each duplicates splitted in a different list with another linq code.

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new List<Info> {
            new Info { Id = 1, Name = "Fabrice", Age = 52},
            new Info { Id = 2, Name = "Eric", Age = 52},
            new Info { Id = 3, Name = "Hervé", Age = 52},
            new Info { Id = 4, Name = "Hugo", Age = 16 },
            new Info { Id = 5, Name = "Léo", Age = 16 },
            new Info { Id = 6, Name = "Noé", Age = 13 },
            new Info { Id = 7, Name = "Estéban", Age = 13 },
            new Info { Id = 8, Name = "Fabrice", Age = 52},
            new Info { Id = 9, Name = "Hugo", Age = 16 },
            new Info { Id = 10, Name = "Noé", Age = 13 },
            new Info { Id = 11, Name = "Fabrice", Age = 52},
        };

    List<Info> lstDuplicates = list.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Age })
        .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
        .SelectMany(g => g)
        .ToList();

    foreach (var duplicate in lstDuplicates)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Duplicate -> {0}", duplicate.ToString());
    }
}

public class Info
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Id : {0}, Name : {1}, Age : {2}", Id, Name, Age);
    }
}
```

This code give :

```
Duplicate -> Id : 1, Name : Fabrice, Age : 52
Duplicate -> Id : 8, Name : Fabrice, Age : 52
Duplicate -> Id : 11, Name : Fabrice, Age : 52
Duplicate -> Id : 4, Name : Hugo, Age : 16
Duplicate -> Id : 9, Name : Hugo, Age : 16
Duplicate -> Id : 6, Name : Noé, Age : 13
Duplicate -> Id : 10, Name : Noé, Age : 13
```

but now, i'd like to separate the duplicates like that :

```
// A result in an IEnumerable<List<Info>> with 3 items
// First item
Duplicate -> Id : 1, Nom : Fabrice, Age : 52
Duplicate -> Id : 8, Nom : Fabrice, Age : 52
Duplicate -> Id : 11, Nom : Fabrice, Age : 52

// Second item
Duplicate -> Id : 4, Nom : Hugo, Age : 16
Duplicate -> Id : 9, Nom : Hugo, Age : 16

// Third item
Duplicate -> Id : 6, Nom : Noé, Age : 13
Duplicate -> Id : 10, Nom : Noé, Age : 13
```

How can I do this in a single LINQ expression from the original list ?

Comment: Start by getting rid of the `SelectMany`. Since that is what is putting them all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use select insteat of select many and change `g` to `g.toList()`:

---

```
var list = new List<Info> {
            new Info { Id = 1, Name = "Fabrice", Age = 52},
            new Info { Id = 2, Name = "Eric", Age = 52},
            new Info { Id = 3, Name = "Hervé", Age = 52},
            new Info { Id = 4, Name = "Hugo", Age = 16 },
            new Info { Id = 5, Name = "Léo", Age = 16 },
            new Info { Id = 6, Name = "Noé", Age = 13 },
            new Info { Id = 7, Name = "Estéban", Age = 13 },
            new Info { Id = 8, Name = "Fabrice", Age = 52},
            new Info { Id = 9, Name = "Hugo", Age = 16 },
            new Info { Id = 10, Name = "Noé", Age = 13 },
            new Info { Id = 11, Name = "Fabrice", Age = 52},
        };

        IEnumerable<List<Info>> lstDuplicates = list.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Age })
            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
            .Select(g => g.ToList());
```

Answer (score 2):

To get `IEnumerable<List<Info>>` with list of duplicates for every group you should use `Select(g => g.ToList())` instead of [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1) (which returns a flattened list of duplicates)

```cs
var lstDuplicates = list.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Age })
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .Select(g => g.ToList());
```

In your case you just need to convert every group to list